# git proper way to fix topic after branch merge

Tags: git, merge, git-rewrite-history

I'm new to Git and for now I'm only working with a local repository but I will eventually share my work with other developers. I'm trying to figure out what is the proper way of fixing code on a topic branch after it's been merged back to the master branch. Here's what I have:

[image]

My topic was implemented in C2 in a topic branch and then merged on the master branch. There's been another commit C5 on master for a different topic. Now I just found an issue in with the feature implemented in C2. Should I fix it in the topic branch as C6 then merge again on the master branch? Or should I just get rid of the topic branch since it's been already merged and just fix it directly in the master branch?

Ideally I would like to keep the C2 and C6 in a single commit so that when we implement remote repository I can push a clean history. But I don't think I can just squash C2 and C6 because of the merge. Is there a way to do this?

**What would be considered good practice to fix a topic after it's been merged?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be helpful for you to learn about `git rebase` for managing your local history. For example, consider this history of commands, which I think roughly recreates your situation and and a possible resolution using `git rebase -i` to rearrange your local history:

```
mkdir tmpfoo
cd tmpfoo/
git init
touch bar
git add .
git commit -am 'c1'
git checkout -b topic
touch baz
git add .
git commit -am 'c2'
git checkout master
touch foo 
git add .
git commit -am 'c3'
git merge topic
touch quux
git add .
git commit -am 'c5'
git checkout topic 
echo b >> baz 
git commit -am 'c6'
git checkout master
git merge topic
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
*   577f974 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'topic'
|\
| * 6750b0d (topic) c6
* | 08ebbf2 c5
* |   0cef647 Merge branch 'topic'
|\ \
| |/
| * f1e6882 c2
* | 0e19228 c3
|/
* 90e6149 c1
19933  git rebase -i 90e6149
>>edit the sequence of commits to something like the following:
pick 0e19228 c3
pick 08ebbf2 c5
pick f1e6882 c2
s 6750b0d c6
19934  git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* 0e3afe0 (HEAD, master) c2
* 7611fb9 c5
* 0e19228 c3
| * 6750b0d (topic) c6
| * f1e6882 c2
|/
* 90e6149 c1
git diff ORIG_HEAD # no output here, the rebase didn't change the working tree's state
```

Comment: Thanks @jonderry, this looks like what I need. If I understand correctly you remove c4 from the history with the rebase interactive, and instead of merging the topic branch you leave it there and can potentially use it later if other rebase are needed?

Comment: Yes, if you think you might need your old work from before rearranging, it's a good idea to leave the branch for a while so you don't have to search through your reflog to find your old partial work. The interactive rebase can reorder commits and "squash" several commits into one larger commit.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer and replace your aliases for `commit` and `checkout`

Comment: I think the answer would benefit from some extra explanation; specifically I'm confused about the line `19933  git rebase -i 90e6149`. Maybe add a '% ' prompt before commands to make it more obvious what' input and what's output. So you are heavily reordering the commits, but it's probably as undesirable as fixing the topic and merging again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of a hack to do that. It works only if the master branch is containing in the remote repository and you can always pull it from there. Then you should do the following steps in your local repository:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git reset --hard <C3>` - reset to the commit before merge commit
3. `git checkout topic`
4. do what you want to do in C6
5. `git commit --amend` - this allows you to save C6 in C2 actually
6. `git checkout master`
7. `git pull origin master` - to pull all the commits you've reset from remote repository
8. `git merge topic`

Please, note that you can do this only if master branch is not your local branch, but stored in remote repository. Also that works only if you haven't pushed your work to remote repository yet.

Comment: It doesn't sound like he has a remote repository.

Comment: Could I create a copy of this repository and use it as a remote to implement the "hack" you describe?

Comment: @ZuoLi, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I can apply it directly. I also updated my question, I guess what I'm looking for is best practice on how to handle such a situation. I'm not experienced enough with Git to know that what I'm asking for is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: In this case the solution would be even uglier: I can think of creating another branch from master, say, `git branch temp`, the same as master, then do all the stuff from my answer. Instead of pulling from origin repo we use `git cherry-pick C5` from temp branch. And finally delete temp branch.

Comment: @loopkin, I really think it is better to keep all related stuff in the same branch. You said you are working in your local repository for now, this means all these tricks are possible and they won't look ugly in remote repo after pushing as they are untraceable.

Comment: @ZuoLi well, assuming I had a remote repo and that I had fetched the master branch when it was at C0, when I push my changes it would push all commits on my master branch right? So C4 and C7 would appear as 2 different commits. That's what I wanted to avoid. Or am I overthinking? Should I not care?

Comment: @loopkin, in both answeres you'll end with only one (amended) commit C2 in branch topic and only one merge commit in master (after C5, say, C7)

Answer (score 0):

The "C6-C7" scenario reflects the history most clearly regarding what had happened (even if it was not ideal).

When you are working alone and know about all the branches that exist, you can just as well add the fix to the `Master` branch (it also shows what happened in the history).

As long as you don't consider "undoing" the `Topic` from `Master` both solutions should be equivalent.

You could also save the files as committed for `C5`, then "reset hard" to `C3`, fix the `Topic`, merge the `Topic` again (virtually the first time), and then put back the saved files and do a manual merge (using `git diff` to evaluate the differences) before committing `C5'`.
That is "messing with the history".
I think that is what https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474391/6607497 suggests with different commands.

In general I'd be careful with rebase commands.

Comment: In a similar scenario (no commits on `Master` yet) I decided to "stash the changes, fix the `Topic`, reset hard to pre-merge on `Master`, merge again, and then "stash pop" (with manual merge) the saved changes before committing.