# How to fix a bug in a branch after it has already been merged with master?

Tags: git, github

Below is my current process. The idea is stable master. We make our changes on our own branches and then merge with master.

- git checkout -b branch-name
- git push origin branch-name
- *make my changes*
- git add .
- *remove unnecessary changes with git checkout HEAD — path-to-file*
- git commit -m “commit message”
- git push origin branch-name
- git checkout master
- git pull origin master
- git merge branch-name
- git push origin master
- *if I then notice a bug in my code, I just use the same branch to fix the problem, and re-merge with master*

Does this seem correct to you? Is there a better flow?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can fix bug in master branch and push it directly to master.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26473633/6607497

Answer (score 2):

You can do changes on your branch and merge them to master again, but as I can see you have already pushed both master and your branch to remote repository. Remember that you should not amend commits already pushed to the remote, so you cannot use `git commit -a`!

Maybe easier and cleanier way to do it would be to fix changes on your branch and then **cherrypick** just this one commit with fixes. It would look like this (assuming you are on master right now)

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>

fix bugs

$ git commit -m "fixes"
$ git push origin <branch-name>
$ git log
```

from git log get  the **commit Id**, it would look like this:

```
commit 4cc1c6ec2d5dc2ce21557681c9abddced1a56645
Author: your name <e-mail>
Date:   Wed Nov 30 10:51:45 2016 +0100
commit message
```

Now copy commit ID and use it co move fixes to master

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick 4cc1c6ec2d5dc2ce21557681c9abddced1a56645
$ git push origin master
```

This way you will have the same commit with fixes on both master and your branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can fix your bugs in your branch . Then add, commit, push and merge with master.

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>

Fix bugs here

$ git commit -am 'Fix bugs'        # add and commit
$ git push origin HEAD             

$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git pull origin <branch-name>
$ git push origin HEAD
```