# How to copy commits from one branch to master branch?

Tags: android, git

I am using Android studio and commandline both. I have a feature branch that has become a superset of my master branch.

I want to merge all diff commits from this feature branch to master branch. How this can be done.

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials out there on how to use git, and merging changes from one branch to another is one of the most basic things they'll cover. If I'm missing something, and this isn't a straight-forward merge, perhaps you can [edit] to explain more clearly.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883743/how-to-fix-a-bug-in-a-branch-after-it-has-already-been-merged-with-master/40886049#40886049

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cherry pick:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#cherry-pick

This way you can checkout master, then apply (cherry pick) specific commit from other branch (your feature branch).

Enjoy